# Using javascript to automatically log into websites

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a program with Javascript that I can use to automatically log into websites. The website I'm testing it on is ATT, as I'm trying to log in and look at my cell phone bill. when I run the program below, It takes me to an ATT page that says they are currently performing maintenance, and to try again later. I know this to be false as I was able to manually sign in just a few seconds later. I don't have a lot of experience with javascript, and much of this code has been pulled from other online sources, so I'm unsure if I'm missing something that needs to be included or it's simply a fact that ATT uses some other login type that this code does not work with. I tried looking at the pages source code, and I didn't see a reference to any type of form, not sure if that matters for this particular situation.

Here is the code:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Login</TITLE>
      <script>
         <!--
           function login() {
           document.form1.action="https://www.att.com/";
           document.form1.submit();
          }
         //-->
      </script>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY onLoad="login()">
      <FORM NAME="form1" id=form1 METHOD="POST">
        <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="userid" VALUE="Username">
        <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="password" VALUE="Password">
        <input type="hidden" name="reqURI" value="/rhwc/smu">
      </FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Your inputs don't have the same names as the ones on the at&t site…

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes?

Comment: Login Action - https://www.att.com/olam/loginAction.olamexecute

Comment: Fields - `wireless_num`: username    `pass`: password   `actionEvent: dotComLogin`   `rememberme: YES`...

Comment: @bros So I need to change both the login address, as well as add `actionEvent: dotComLogin rememberme: YES` to the function?

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 you can try it and see if it works...No guarantees it is going to work I don't know what kind of security they have around their login process.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 also change `userid` to `wireless_num` and `password` to `pass`...

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 check out my answer it does work I've tried it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this I've tried it and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="https://www.att.com/olam/loginAction.olamexecute">
Username:<input type="text" name="wireless_num"/>
Password:<input type="password" name="pass"/>
<input type="hidden" value="YES" name="rememberme"/>
<input type="hidden" value="dotComLogin" name="actionEvent"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but not in the way I originally intended it to. your code creates  a form in which I have to click submit on in order to sign in, where as I was looking for something that automatically signs in when I launch the program. I'm giving you the green check because I feel like I will be able to modify this in order to get the results I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 yes you can do the same thing you were trying to do just submit the form using javascript like you are doing in your question...

Answer (score 1):

1. **Wrong names**
   The `name`s of your `<input>` elements don't match the names on the ATT site. The server won't expect the names you have, and won't process data in those fields.
2. **Wrong action (probably)**
   I somehow doubt that the server-side script that handles logins on the ATT site is on the homepage. More likely it's on `/login` or `/log-in`, etc. If you POST the form to the wrong script, then no data will get processed from it and you don't get logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The id and name attributes are not the same. It is the name attribute of the input field that is going to be send together with the value you type.

If you inspect the User ID field you can see the following HTML:

```
<input id="userid" class="text" name="wireless_num" ...>
```

In your code, you are submitting the username under the name 'userid'. However, it should be submitted under 'wireless_num'.